# Detect whether a vehicle touched a white line drawn on ground in realtime

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, robotics

I am currently working on a project where I take real time frames from an IP camera using RTSP protocol and do some processing on it.

The footage will be of vehicles captured from 3 different angles including its top view. I want to find whether the vehicle touches white lines drawn on the ground. I did it with OpenCV using background masking method. It worked for me. But then the shadow of the vehicle started causing problems as long shadows (during morning and evening hours) are detected as foreground crossing the white lines. So then I applied a shadow cancellation algorithm on it. but its too heavy and is causing too much delay so it wont work I real time.

I am planning to use deep learning to do the same now. I trained a resnet18 based model to do the task. but it is not generalizing and is getting overfit. So it is only able to detect those images I trained it. when I implement it, it started to show false results.

I would  like to have help in solving this project. What could the the best way I should have done this. Sorry if it is not the correct place to ask. Also do ask if any more information is needed.

sample image :

[image]

Regards.

Comment: [mre] required. that means data. your own research and attempts are required as well. [ask]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have  added a sample image. I need to fin whether a vehicle crossed the white line.

Comment: from *that picture*, you can't reliably run a robot in that track, or detect anything touching the outer line.